# I'm new to UI design but i've been on other artes(like web design, logo and other)

Tags: interface-design, ios, wireframing

It's my first time to UI design in iOS and I was given a project app. My question is:

Which is better to UI design, Photoshop or Illustrator (I love them both)?
What is my resolution (and what are your tips and settings)?

I have some idea design in my mind but I'm not sure if this are iOS standards.

After designing what is 'THE BEST' mock up/wire-frame(high fidelity)/prototyping tool that is easy to use(least coding please)

Also do you have any templates/layouts you could share?

Comment: Hi @Tristan. Stack Exchange follows a strict Q&A format. Your question is unfortunately not a question, but six questions rolled into one. It would take a book to answer properly. I flagged it for closure as it stands. You could salvage it by narrowing the scope of the question. See the [help] for guidelines on questions.

Comment: Daunting task for something you've never done! To get you started, try searching for mobile UI best practices. In terms of resolution, it really depends on what device you're building for. It's common to design 2 layouts that allow your app to choose between a 4:3 aspect ratio (for tablets) or a 16:9 aspect ratio (most phones, but not all). Also, for low-fidelity prototyping, check out Invisionapp.com (high fidelity prototyping you aren't going to find without some code support). Best of luck!

Comment: Also, since you mentioned you're designing for iOS, take a look at Apple's UI guidelines here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/. Some good tips in there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be more apriete for ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm working as a Digital Designer at Fox Sports Australia. I've implemented for our new templates and every type of UI designs to us **Sketch** if you are a mac user. 
https://www.sketchapp.com/

If you use windows there is a great software coming up from adobe called **Project Comet**
http://landing.adobe.com/en/na/products/creative-cloud/comet/229818-notifyme.html

The best thing about Sketch is that you can add plugins and other softwares which makes life easier.

Enjoy!